# Boost converter high output impedance

Tags: solar-cell, impedance, boost, output

At no load my boost converter will be the same as in the photo. I'm thinking without a load at the end of the boost circuit the output impedance will be very high which will make the potential difference after connecting the output to a (Semikron an-8005) which has an input impedance of 30k will make the boost output decrease to around 70V and if I take the output of the Semikron inverter to a filter and then 1K load after that the voltage will decrease even more to around 6V only.

How can I avoid this drop?

Will putting a very high resistor in parallel with the output capacitor of the boost solve this drop?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should consider dynamically adjusting the mark-space ratio to keep the output voltage level fairly constant across a wide range of loads. The picture below should give you an idea: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [dos4ever.com](http://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/boost2.gif))</sub>

> Is putting a very high resistor in parallel with the output capacitor
>   of the boost will solve this drop?

No, this will have no beneficial effect at all.